# When should we set the C++ Windows desktop application's entry point?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, desktop-application, entry-point

I'm a bit confused as to what the best practices are for setting entry points for C++ applications, I've tried to find some answers to this but everything I've seen deals with *how* to do it rather than *why*.

Let's say I have a Windows desktop application with 2 build configurations: Debug and Release. Debug has subsystem `SYSTEM:CONSOLE` so that I can run and see specific logs in a console window while Release has subsystem `SYSTEM:WINDOWS`.

By default, Debug's entry point would be `main` whereas Release's entry point would be `WinMain`. This means defining `main(args)` and `WinMain(args)` in my `main.cpp`. Here are a few questions I have on this:

- Is it better practice to set the Entry Point for Release to be `mainCRTStartup` and not have `WinMain(args)` or to have both `main` and `WinMain` defined in `main.cpp`?
- Are there significant differences or risks in setting the Entry Point?
- Do any of these answers change if my application supports Unicode i.e. using `wmain`/`wWinMain`?
- If this isn't a good example to be using the Entry Point settings, what would be one? And if this *is* a good example of using Entry Point settings, what would be an example of not using the Entry Point settings?

Comment: I would leave everything on SYSTEM:WINDOWS and allocate a console if desired. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say use the same entry point for both and skip the console build entirely. Instead use the VS debug console.

The only time you would use the custom entry point is if you aren't using the MS C runtime at all. And I have never had reason to do so.

Comment: I wonder if you use a custom entry point if you skip over e.g. initialization of global objects?  That would be very very bad.

Comment: Do you mean to just have both configs to use the same subsystem so that goes into either `main` or `WinMain` then? So like what Retired Ninja suggested, just allocate a console if we need one?

Comment: This does answer my question though, if we're using MS C runtime we should just use the default entry points and not mess around with it. Thank you.